# awk to match pattern in html and use regex

Tags: regex, awk

Using `awk` to parse an `html` and it does execute but prints the entire line not just the percentage as in the desired. My thinking is that the pattern `reads passed filters:` is matched, then the `regex` is used to use the `</td><td class='col2'>78.760142 M` and print the field after. There are aditional lines above and below, but the are different then the pattern. Thank you :).

file

```
...
...
<tr><td class='col1'>reads passed filters:</td><td class='col2'>78.760142 M (95.514721%)</td></tr>
...
...
```

awk

```
awk -F'reads passed filters:[^a-z][0-9][::space::][a-z][::space::]*' '/reads passed filters:/ {sub("[^a-z][0-9][::space::][a-z][::space::].*", "", $1); print $1}' file
```

current

```
<tr><td class='col1'>reads passed filters:</td><td class='col2'>78.760142 M (95.514721%)</td></tr>
```

desired

```
95.514721%
```

Comment: Using `sed` instead of `awk` to avoid bothering with meaningless field-splitting : `sed -nE 's/.*reads passed filters:.*\(([0-9.]+%)\).*/\1/p'` (try it [here](https://ideone.com/ar3TzA)). That said you'd better use an HTML-aware tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
sed -nE 's/.*reads passed filters:.*\(([0-9.]+%)\).*/\1/p' file
```

It uses a substitution that will match a whole line that contains "reads passed filters" followed later by a percentage and replace it by the percentage alone.